# I am getting Automation server could not create object in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, activex

1. plugin = new ActiveXObject('Crusher.Plugin');
2. var strVersion = plugin.Version();

getting error in line 1. while creating active X object.

I tried IE9 browser setting(custom level) but i need this in coding part
i.e.
any javascript or dojo that solves the problem or can change the active x setting in IE will
be very appreciable.

Thanks,

Deepak

Comment: Accessing programmatically ActiveX settings needs an ActiveXObject : ). Otherway it's called hacking or malicious attack...

Comment: Can you provide me some example code for accessing ActiveXObject.          I Did not mean any hacking or malicious attack.

Comment: If the browser options don't allow you to to use an ActiveX, only you can do, is to alert to the user to change ActiveX options to allow you execute some code. There's no walkaround for this.